# Using Karma / Mocha get Uncaught TypeError -> this[opt] is not a function

Tags: javascript, karma-mocha

I'm just installing Karma / Mocha trying to work it with React. I get a mysterious error saying that this[opt] is not a function. Not sure what to make of it.

I have the following Karma Config file:

```
let webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: true,
    frameworks: ['mocha'],
    files: ['app/tests/**/*.test.jsx'],
    preprocessors: {
      'app/tests/**/*.test.jsx': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
    },
    reporters: ['mocha'],
    client: {
      mocha: {
        timout: '5000'
      }
    },
    webpack: webpackConfig,
    webpackServer: {
      noInfo: true
    }
  });
};
```

with the simple test:

```
'use strict'
let expect = require('expect');

describe('App', () => {
  it('should properly run tests', () => {
    expect(1).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

The browser starts with the test but I get the following error:

Chrome 52.0.2743 (Mac OS X 10.11.3) ERROR
  Uncaught TypeError: this[opt] is not a function
  at /Users/bpr/Documents/ReactTimer/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:124

Comment: Are you using 'chai'?

Comment: No, ->     "expect": "^1.20.2",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "mocha": "^2.5.3",

Comment: should I be using chai?

Comment: Yes, if you can change your library. But if this do not work probably other message error would appear and will be more helpful.
And then return to 'expect' but I prefer 'chai'

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
client: {
  mocha: {
    timout: '5000'
  }
}
```

The word *timout* is a typo - should be *timeout*